# Using a vintage lab balance scale with a chain-dial

Tags: equipment

I have obtained an an antique Philip Harris balance scale in good, but condition aside from a lot of corrosion on the brass. I can't find a model number on it and am not sure of it's actual age, but I am guessing 1950's. It has a chain-dial on it, which is something that I'm not familiar with. I've not been able to figure out how to actually use the chain-dial or indeed any information on them. In cleaning up the scale I found that the guide for the plumb line was not correctly attached so it's possible that the chain-dial isn't attached right either.

Can anyone explain in detail how the chain-dial is used or direct me to some documentation or textbook resource on using a scale of this nature.

Comment: This is a case where including an image might help.

Comment: This user manual for a 1913 balance may or may not be helpful: https://www2.humboldt.edu/scimus/Instruments/UseCareBal/UseCareBal.htm as well as details of some different "chainomatic" balances from Becker: https://www2.humboldt.edu/scimus/Instruments/ChainBal-BKH/ChainBal.htm

Comment: Sorry I tried to include an image but stack exchange gave a server error and was unable to upload it.